# Opamp stability issue

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: PSpice Opamp Figure]

Hi, I am trying to use non iverting OPAMP configuration with LM324 and I have 3.869mV output which idealy should be 5.3V based on my calculation. I am wondering what is the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure that pin 6 is actually connected to the rest of the circuit? You have a proper connection dot at the top of R5 and nowhere else. Check the voltage on pin 6 itself.

Comment: The polarity of the 16V battery, as indicated by its symbol, doesn't agree with the voltage labels. Try rotating that battery by 180 degrees.

Comment: @James, V2 is connected to the + terminal of a voltage source set to -16 V. That makes the output -16 V. I've fallen for that in the past.

Comment: @Transistor ok, I see.

Answer (score 2):

As Transistor says, (maybe) you're missing a connection from R1/R2 to the input. The input should be no more negative than one diode drop provided the model is realistic.

Your resistors are a bit low at 1K. Changing them all to 10K would be better.

There is no guarantee the LM324 will start up properly if you drive an input below the negative rail as it is starting up. There is a phenomenon called "phase reversal". See page 6 in this [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa277/sloa277.pdf?ts=1620001915439&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

I strongly suggest a Schottky diode from the inverting input to ground (eg. BAT54 or 1N5819).

You should also have capacitors on the LM317 input and output but they're not essential for stability and won't cause an issue with your simulation.

---

Here is a simulation in LTspice using the National Semiconductor LM324 model, with and without the diode:

[image]

[image]

With the resistors reduced to 1K the voltage at the inverting input is about -2V in my simulation. More than I would expect in reality.

For what it's worth, a quick reality check with a similar Thevenin source (-8V with 1.5K in series) gives  -970mV at the non-inverting input of a generic LM324.

Comment: @Transistor. I'm confused. There is also no dot between R3 and R4, but the negative voltage indicates that there is connection.

Comment: With -2.935 volts on the left leg on R2, there must be a connection to R1.

Comment: Agree with both comments. There something awry there though, as the input should not be -3V wrt negative rail. Might be the model.

Comment: Yes. The voltages across R1 and R2 differ by ~400 mV so, there is also current at the inverting pin (> 400 uA).

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach? Using a single supply and relying on negative voltages + inverting configuration may cause problems as Spehro Pefhany mentioned.

I've not preserved the same resistor values for simplicity (round voltage values). You may create a "virtual ground" for you circuit or, even simpler, provide a voltage offset to your circuit:

[image]

The above circuit is equivalent to:

[image]

Now the "reference" is 5V. I've changed the configuration to non-inverting and switched the polarity of the 16V input.

Now the input is \$(4 V - 5 V) = -1 V\$

The non-inverting gain is \$1 + \frac{R_4}{R_7} = 2\$.

The output is \$(3 V - 5 V) = -2 V\$